# How to check that a sequence of numbers is random?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, random, random-walk, random-functions

I have a sequence of numbers 
like 1,7,22,45,12,96,21,45,65,36,85,14,51,16,18,17,16....65...

> IS there any formula to check whether the sequence is random or not ?

In my case

1. odd  numbers are not random since previous+2
2. even numbers are not random
3. the numbers can be repeated in a sequence but must be far away,
4. we cannot generate the sequence using any formula like  (x+2)^2 -2x like...

Comment: And how do you define _random_?

Comment: @Sasha In my case 1.odd numbers are not random since previous+2 2.even numbers are not random 3.the numbers can be repeated in a sequence but must be far away, 4.we cannot generate the sequence using any formula like (x+2)^2 -2x like...

Comment: Would the distant digits of $\pi$ count as random - even though they are computable? Randomness is a difficult concept to capture, and is also very important, since the generation of random (or pseudorandom - ie looking random on common tests) numbers is commercially important [think codes and confidential communication]. A readily computable formula or algorithm to identify and predict all pseudorandom sequences would have significant consequences in the real world.

Comment: Your property 3. is **opposite** to randomness.

Comment: Maybe this will be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good discussion of this question in Seminumerical Algorithms, which is Volume 2 of Knuth's The Art Of Computer Programming.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to tell what "random" means...

But in the algorithmic context there is a nice definition.

To be more specific: a number $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is algorithmically random if for every $n$ the size of the shortest program giving you the first $n$ bits of $\alpha$ is at least $n$ bits long.

You can encode your sequence as a binary representation of some number from the interval $[0,1]$ and try to check if it is algorithmically random.

But do not count on a formula that can tell you if a particular number (sequence) is random since such a formula cannot exist.

See "Algorithmically random sequence" "Chaitin constant" and "halting problem" in Wikipedia for more details.